# Can we call domain as inverse image of a function?

Tags: analysis, functions

I was going through the definition of inverse image of a function http://www.northeastern.edu/suciu/U565/MATH4565-sp10-handout1.pdf, and I was wondering if inverse image of a function is the domain of the function itself. Please give me some examples   on it.

Comment: You use the phrase `inverse image of a function`, but what does that mean? We define the inverse image of *sets* under functions. We do speak of the image of a function, though, when the domain is understood. (Formally, we consider the domain part of the data of a function.) It is true that the domain of a function is *equal* to the inverse image of the codomain, and also equal to the inverse image of the image of $f$, but that is not the definition of "domain."

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes. Actually I mean "inverse image of image under   a function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Inverse image of a function" doesn't make much sense( unless it is taken as inverse image of the co-domain ); you need to specify some subset of co-domain and then we can talk about "inverse image of set $B\subset$ co-domain w.r.t. function $f$".

Consider a function $f:A\to B$. Let $C\subset A$ and $D\subset B$ such that $f(C)=D$ i.e. $D=$ the set of elements of $B$ to which elements of $C$ are mapped.

Then inverse image of $D$ is precisely the subset of $A$ which is mapped to $D$ which is none other than $C$[image]

Here $f(C)=D$ and $f^{-1}(D)=C$ which might not be the whole $A$, in fact, $f^{-1}(D)=A\iff f(A)=D$

Comment: Just knowing that $f(C)=D$ isn't enough to conclude that $f^{-1}(D)=C.$ (Consider a constant function $f$ and $C$ a strict subset of its domain.) All it tells us in general is that $f^{-1}(D)\supseteq C$.

Comment: @CameronBuie But if the function is one-to-one and onto (i.e. Bijective) then $f(C)=D$ will be true. Right? (I know here a general function $f$ is considered, I am just clarifying a point)

Comment: @Frank: If $f$ is injective and $f(C)=D,$ then we can conclude that $f^{-1}(D)=C,$ yes.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Given a function $f$ and a set $U$, the inverse image **of** $U$ **under** $f$ (it is necessary to specify both the set *and* the function, here) will be the domain of $f$ ***if and only if*** $U$ contains the image of $f$ (that is, $U$ is a [codomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) of $f$).

For an example to see why the set is important, let $f(x)=|x|.$ The inverse image of $\{1\}$ under $f$ is $\{-1,1\},$ but the inverse image of $\Bbb R$ under $f$ is $\Bbb R.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$ commonly written $f:X \rightarrow Y$. If we define the inverse function $f^{-1}: Y \rightarrow X$ as $f^{-1}(y) = x$ if $f(x) = y$, then $f^{-1}(Y) \subset X = \text{Dom}(f)$. However, there need to be further conditions on $f$ for $f^{-1}(Y) = X$. That is, $f$ must be a bijection: Every element in $Y$ is an image of $f$ for some value $x \in X$, and $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$.
For example, $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \left\{ 0 \right\}$, $f(x) = x^2$ is a function that is not a bijection (for example, $f(-1) = f(1) = 1$). Likewise, $f^{-1} ( \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \left\{ 0 \right\} ) \subset \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \left\{ 0 \right\} \subset \mathbb{R}$. However, $f(x) = x^3$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is a bijection, and so the image of $R$ under $f^{-1}$ is $\mathbb{R} = \text{Dom}( f )$.